# Apply IBInspectable to all view types in iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I'm trying to apply `IBInspectable` to all types of view like `UIView`, `UIButton`, `UITextField`, `UIImageView`, etc.
Here's what I did:

```
@IBDesignable
class BaseView: UIView
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateCornerRadius()
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4 {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    private func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = rounded ? cornerRadius : 0
    }
}
```

It is working fine with all `UIView` using `BaseView` subclasses in storyboard, but how can I use this for buttons, text fields, image views, etc?

May be using protocols or extensions to avoid repeating this code to all other types of views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an extension instead of a subclass, and access the layer property directly:

```
extension UIView
{
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius;
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.cornerRadius = value;
        }
    }

    var rounded: Bool {
        return layer.cornerRadius > 0.0;
    }
}
```

Note: Since you're not implementing `drawRect` using `@IBDesignable` is needless. You can't implement `rounded`as a settable property this way, but you can have a read-only property for that.

Comment: this is not possible, coz extensions can't have stored properties!

Comment: @D4ttatraya: My extension doesn't have a stored property.

Comment: In your extension, `cornerRadius` is stored property... check, compiler will give you an error

Comment: @D4ttatraya: Nope, that isn't true. Xcode 9.2 shows no errors. Actually, I've used this code in own projects. However, you can't implement `rounded` this way.

Comment: @D4ttatraya This is called computed property, you can search for it online, extension can have this kind of variable

Comment: Yes, I said I got it!

Answer (score 0):

It is the subClass of `UIView`. To use the these class you have to create subClass of `UIImage`, `UIButton` etc.

So create subclasses of each component like this

```
class ButtonSubClass: UIButton {}// for button subclass

class ImageSubClass: UIImage {}// for image subclass
```

Comment: yes, but I need to repeat all code for all types of base classes! that's what I want to avoid...

Comment: You can not change the subclass of any component into another component.